# How to play an audio file into Tone.Offline buffer output

Tags: tonejs

## Question

How do I play a local audio file inside `Tone.Offline` so that when it finishes and return it's promised buffer it will contain the played audio?

### Code

```js
Tone.Offline(({ transport }) => {
    const p = new Tone.Player(src, () => {
        transport.start();
    }).toDestination();
    
    transport.schedule((time) => {
        p.start(time + 5).stop(time + 9); //this never happen!
    });
}, 10).then((buffer) => { // how do I push parts of my audio file onto the buffer?
    const wav = toWav(buffer);
    saveAs(new Blob([wav], { type: "audio/wav" }), "./blibli.wav");
});
```

### Issue

I've noticed the callback part inside `transport.schedule` never happen,
and so I never get to build the final buffer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tone.Offline(({ transport }) => {
    const p = new Tone.Player(src, () => {
        transport.start();
    }).toDestination();

    transport.schedule((time) => {
        p.start(time + 5).stop(time + 9); //this never happen!
    });

    // ********
    transport.start(); // Add this line!
    // ********

}, 10).then((buffer) => { 
    const wav = toWav(buffer);
    saveAs(new Blob([wav], { type: "audio/wav" }), "./blibli.wav");
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).